# How to match multiple criteria and get a message

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA I would like to match 3 criteria out 3 columns and get a message if there is any match.

My code so far is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("A1:A10").Value = "America" And Range("B1:B10").Value = "cloudy" 
      And Range("C1:C10").Value > 30 Then
        MsgBox "This is the promised land!"
    End If
End Sub
```

I get an error that there is a problem with different values.

[image: Worksheet]

Comment: `Range("A1:A10")` Doesn't select all cells one by one. Consider looping through the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach but works similar.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 10 ' Put something more variable instead of 10
   If Range("A" & i).Value = "Value4" And Range("B" & i).Value = "Value8" And Range("C" & i).Value > 30 Then
      MsgBox "Test"
   End If
Next i
```

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 1):

Loop over each row:

```
Sub ceckit()
    Dim cell As Range, A As Range
    Set A = Range("A1:A10")
    For Each cell In A
        With cell
            If .Value = "America" And .Offset(0, 1).Value = "cloudy" And .Offset(0, 2).Value > 30 Then
                MsgBox "This is the promised land!"
            End If
        End With
    Next cell
End Sub
```